# Sorting list, error "not respond"

Tags: c, sorting, struct

What's wrong with me sorting code?
When I open my program I see error "program not respond". Please check me code.

```
void sorting(el_list **first)
{
   el_list *newfirst = NULL;
   el_list *min, *prevmin, *tmp;

   while( first )
   {
      min = first;
      prevmin = NULL;
      tmp = first;
      while(tmp->next)
      {
        if (tmp->next->record.score < min->record.score)
        {
          prevmin = tmp;
          min = tmp->next;
        }
        tmp = tmp->next;
      }
      if (prevmin) prevmin->next = min->next;
      else first = min->next;
      min->next = newfirst;
      newfirst = min;
   }
  first = newfirst;
}
```

Comment: See how your one line `if` statements got me lost, any good reason to choose that style? That error means that your program is looping infinitely, did you try to use a debugger and watch where `first` is pointing to?

Comment: Debugger is stopped at line:
     if (tmp->next->record.score < min->record.score)
error: Segmentation fault.

Comment: You're assigning `el_list **` (`first`) to `el_list *` (`min`, `newfirst`, etc.). Your assignments to/from `first` should use `*first` instead - `*first = newfirst`, `min = *first`, etc. There should be a number of compiler warnings about this.

Comment: I change `first` to `*first` but it don't work too.

Comment: Any other compiler warnings that need attention?

Comment: Now debugger stopped at line: `while(tmp->next)` Oh, I forgot `&` in line where I induce function. But it dont sort :/

Comment: How are you calling it? With an `el_list *`, or with the address of an `el_list *`? If the former, fix that, as a compiler warning probably suggested.

Comment: I calling it `sorting(&first)`

Comment: Also, `while (first)` should be `while (*first)`. And don't miss `else *first = min->next;`

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
 if (tmp->next->record.score < min->record.score)
```

to

```
 if ((min != NULL) && (tmp->next->record.score < min->record.score))
```

always check before dereferencing a pointer.

Comment: `min` is initialized to `first` when `first` is known non-NULL. It's only ever set to `tmp->next` when *that* is known non-NULL. The problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @PaulRoub I thought of this since the OP said that the debugger stopped at that line saying segmentation fault, but you are right, it's not necessarily it. I am deleting this answer in a few seconds.